# Как задать адаптивный фон блока с помощью Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть блок в котором задним фоном должна быть картинка во весь размер и на ней сверху форма и ещё картинка.
Вот мой код. Картинка изменяется но она обреза по высоте.

```css
.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffc000;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/019f0aa5-780a-49fc-b847-41e700bc65f9/s1200);
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="http://www.pngpix.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/PNGPIX-COM-Sale-PNG-Transparent-Image-500x197.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" id="sale">
      <form id="form" role="form" action="" method="post" class="center-block">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <div class="control-group required">
              <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" id="name" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />
              </div>
              <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" id="phone" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />
              </div>
              <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" class="button" value="Отправить" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: В чем тогда должна заключаться адаптивность картинки?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov картинка должна пропорционально уменьшатся или увеличиваться в зависимости от размера экрана(в начале моей страницы находится такая картинка, но задана не как фон а просто картинка)

Comment: Так какая картинка должна быть адаптивной? Фона или та что в форме?

Comment: Вставил в ваш код широкую картинку. Если уменьшить окно браузера, то картинка пропорционально сужается. Собственно непонятно, что хочется получить в итоге.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Картинка фона блока должна быть адаптивной

Comment: Она адаптивна, вы указали `cover`, что означает "лучшее заполнение". Если стороны блока не пропорциональны размерам картинки, то картинка будет обрезана. Вот я и хочу добиться, какое изменение размера вам нужно? Вмещать всю картинку целиком и оставлять белые поля по краям?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov мне нужно чтобы картинка отображалась полностью, во весь размер экрана. Спасибо за понимание

Comment: попробуйте `contain` вместо `cover`